# How to check the particular section or key word exist in appconfig file

Tags: c#, app-config

I have added my own section `<section listeners>` in my app.config file.

How can I check, programmatically, if the new section exist?

Comment: Config files can be complex beasts. Please show us the one you are talking of so that we can better understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sectionName") as SectionType
```

`section` will be `null` if the section isn't there.

Comment: I already used this but .it only get it from section presented properties only.i want to access system.diagnostics property:        Code:                                                              !--system.diagnostics
      add name="TraceLevel" value="1"
    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" initializeData="TraceLog.txt"       
trace                                                                 i want to get the tracelog.txt.how is it possible
  </system.diagnostics>-->

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to access it like a normal XML file.

```
        var config = XDocument.Load("App.Config");
        var element = config
            .Element("section");
        ...
```